# Export default connect and export default class (FluidNavigator)

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I experience a problem.
Export default connect and export default class. How can I use together? Sorry for the basic question, but I'm getting frustrated that nothing I've tried is really working.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FluidNavigator } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions';
import { kriterDegis, denetimKriter } from '../actions';
...
class Kriter extends Component {
...
render()
...
{this.renderButton()}
...

class Screen2 extends React.Component {
render() 
...
const Navigator = FluidNavigator({
  kriter: {screen: Kriter},
  screen2: {screen: Screen2}
});

export default class Myclass extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <Navigator/>
    );
...
const mapToStateProps = ({ kriterResponse }) => {
   const {...
    return { ...
};
export default connect(mapToStateProps, { kriterDegis, denetimKriter })(Kriter);
```

When I change it as below, I get this error when I click on the button in the Kriter class

```
export const ConnectedKriter = connect(mapToStateProps, { kriterDegis, denetimKriter })(Kriter);
```

[enter image description here](https://udemy-images.s3.amazonaws.com/redactor/raw/2018-12-13_07-42-15-d4d93c9f8372ab73098f4d5b2544ab1e.jpg)

Could you please help me on this topic. I appreciate any help that may guide me to the right direction to figure out the cause of the problem. Thanks,

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use redux, you can connect with your main class which is "MyClass".

```
export default connect(mapToStateProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MyClass);
```

You don't have to export your "MyClass" after that.
This line will connect and export your class already.

Comment: I can't use FluidNavigator together with connect.I am getting an error.